# Windows 10 can't see SSD in Disk management but it's visible under Device Manager & BIOS

Tags: windows-10, ssd, disk-management

I have a new Samsung 860 EVO SSD, removed one of the working drives and connected the SSD instead. I see the SSD in the BIOS and under Disk Drives in Device Manager but it's not visible at all under Disk Management and File Explorer. No visible meaning not even as an unallocated drive or a drive needing formatting or needing a drive letter.

I went through the suggestions of running the Memory Diagnostics utility and uninstalling the 'Standard SATA AHCI Controller' from the device manager. Rebooted and noticed the AHCI controller is back. Maybe Windows needs it. 
The boot drive is a regular hard drive. 
I will try placing the boot drive and the SSD in different SATA ports.

Any other suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: In my experience, sometimes the CL version can do things the GUI version can't.  From an administrator command prompt, run `diskpart` then `list disk` and see what you get.

Comment: Also, how old is the computer?  The symptoms remind me of back when SATA1 motherboards were around and some SATA2/3 drives wouldn't work without jumpering them into SATA1 mode.

Comment: list disk shows the two drives that I see in Disk management. Disk 0 is the boot HD and Disk 2 is the external hard drive. No sign of the SSD. The motherboard is MSI H97M-G43 which supports SATA3. The computer was built this year.

Comment: Disk 1 was the other HD which I unplugged and replaced the SSD with but Disk 1 doesn't show anymore in Disk Management and diskpart.

Comment: Does any other drive show, HDD or SSD if you use that port?

Comment: It shows the original HD as disk 1 as I mentioned when it's connected. When the SSD is connected is shows nothing.

Comment: I connected the SSD to another computer and I get the same behavior with it also. Maybe the  SSD has an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a bug where Windows 10 doesn't recognize the SSD if it's not formatted. I used a third party tool formatter and then it showed up in Disk Management.

Comment: Windows 7 has a built-in tool. Just Windows key search for "disk management" or "create and format hard disk partitions". Also look up the cmd "diskpart" command. Might need to use diskpart first.